# How to prove $\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^{2}\binom {n} {r} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$?

Tags: binomial-theorem

How to prove 
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^{2}\binom {n} {r} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$$
By using binomial theorem?

Comment: For a combinatorial proof, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923215/give-a-combinatorial-proof-nn12n-2-sum-k-1nk2-binomnk/1923224#1923224 . Through the binomial theorem, it is enough to apply $(xD)^2$ to both sides of $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}x^r = (1+x)^n,$$ then evaluate at $x=1$.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The OP is explicilty asking for use of the binomial theorem, while the duplicate emphasizes using combinatorial arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You have 
$$
\sum_{r=0}^n{n\choose r}x^r=(1+x)^n.
$$
If you differentiate, 
$$\tag1
\sum_{r=1}^nr{n\choose r}x^{r-1}=n(1+x)^{n-1}.$$
Differentiate again:
$$\tag2
\sum_{r=1}^nr(r-1){n\choose r}x^{r-2}=n(n-1)(1+x)^{n-2}.
$$
If you evaluate $(1)$ at $x=1$,
$$\tag3
\sum_{r=1}^nr{n\choose r}=n\,2^{n-1}
$$
If you evaluate $(2)$ at $x=1$, 
$$\tag4
\sum_{r=1}^nr(r-1){n\choose r}=n(n-1)\,2^{n-2}.
$$
If you add $(3)$ and $(4)$,
$$
\tag5
\sum_{r=1}^nr^2{n\choose r}=n\,2^{n-1}+n(n-1)2^{n-2}=(2n+n(n-1))\,2^{n-2}=n(n+1)\,2^{n-2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{r=1}^n  r^2\binom {n}{r}=n\sum_{r=1}^n  r \binom {n-1}{r-1}$$
$$=n\sum_{r=1}^n  (r-1+1)\binom {n-1}{r-1}$$
$$=n\left[\sum_{r=1}^n  (r-1)\binom {n-1}{r-1} + \sum_{r=1}^n  \binom {n-1}{r-1}\right]$$
$$=n\left[(n-1) \sum_{r=2}^n \binom {n-2}{r-2}+ \sum_{r=1}^n  \binom {n-1}{r-1}\right]$$
$$=n\left[(n-1).2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1}\right]$$
$$=n(n+1).2^{n-2}$$